# How to smooth-scroll javascript scrollLeft in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a horizontal scroll menu for some images. The navigation has to work with arrow buttons:

```
<template>
  <section id="artwork" class="artwork">
    <div class="arrow left" @click="scrollLeft"></div>
    <div class="artwork-container">
      <img :src="state.image1" class="image">
      <img :src="state.image2" class="image">
      <img :src="state.image3" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="arrow right" @click="scrollRight"></div>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
const scrollLeft = (() => {
    document.querySelector('.artwork-container').scrollLeft -= 500
})
const scrollRight = (() => {
    document.querySelector('.artwork-container').scrollLeft += 500
})
</script>
```

2 images are displayed at any time with the arrow buttons to enable scrolling right/left to show the third image. Problem is that the scrolling is not smooth.

I've tried setting:

```
html: {scroll-behaviour: smooth}
```

or using:

```
vue3-smooth-scroll
```

library but it doesn't affect horizontal scroll it seems.

How do I get it smooth? Maybe `Vue3` provides a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

I found that instead of `scollLeft` you can use `scrollTo` which brings some handy options:

```
const scrollRight = (() => {
    document.querySelector('.artwork-container').scrollTo({
        left: 500,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    })
})
```